# Real numbers is the same as a floating-point numbers?

Tags: python, types, floating-point

Floating-point data types are sometimes misleadingly called real numbers (evocative of mathematical real numbers), in a programming lecture my professor treats real numbers as interchangeable with floating-point numbers in his speech, I want to know if mathematically real numbers are the same kind of real numbers in programming? It just confused me.

[Diagram of real numbers with their numerical data types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApBLb.png)

Comment: Of course, there are real numbers that cannot be represented with floats with perfect accuracy. Maybe more technically accurate to think of floats as a subset of rational numbers. Doesn't seem like a fight with picking to me though. In the end, everything is an integer in the computer.

Comment: Floating point is the closest approximation of real numbers.

Comment: Many real numbers cannot be stored in (a finite) memory other than using symbolic representations. This includes transcendental numbers.

Comment: Some programming languages call their floating point data types _real_ (e.g. Fortran, Eiffel)

Comment: There are uncountably many real numbers, and a finite number of them are representable as floats. If you want to approximate a (non-integer) real number, floats are often a good bet.

Comment: Thank you @Prune! I indeed did my research by hours before posting, I'm sorry if the research wasn't enough!

Comment: Then I'm really lost on where you're lost -- what did you search for that you didn't get several dozen good explanations?  I gave you my query, and that bludgeoned the subject to death in the first few hits.

Comment: These answers are horrible.  Too bad the question is closed.  The short answer is YES; however hardware has limitations on the precision it can store.  We use rational numbers to approximate irrational numbers, and then we limit the precision and the amplitude to something convenient for computers.  Binary Floating point vs binary fixed point vs decimal (in binary) fixed point are just a few representations.  Currency is a fixed point digital (in binary). 1.25 as a float looks like 0010000000 00000, where the first 0 of each group is a sign, and the floating binary point is after that 0.

Comment: (continuation):  The first 1 is implied.  The first group represents the precision of the number, and the second group represents how many positions to move the binary point to get the actual (aproximate) number.  So a float is just how a rational number is approximately represented.  But they represent the concept of "Rational Real" in math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematical numeric types don't generally have exact mappings to data types in programming languages.

In mathematics we have rational and irrational numbers (I'm ignoring complex numbers, since these are just pairs of rational and/or irrational numbers). Integers are a subset of rational numbers (where the numerator is an exact multiple of the denominator).

Computers have integers as natural data types, and some programming languges have either built-in rational types or libraries for manipulating them.

Irrational numbers (often called "real numbers" in computer science, even though in mathematics real numbers includes rational numbers), however, can't be represented exactly in computers. By definition, there's no finite representation as digits. So any digital representation must be just an approximation.

Floating point is an efficient way to represent and compute with a large range of numbers efficiently. So this is usually the method of choice when you have an algorithm that needs to process real numbers. For this reason, "real" is sometimes used as a synonym for "floating point". For instance, Fortran and PL/I use the keyword `REAL` when declaring floating point variables. But this terminology has fallen out of favor, and most other languages use the more accurate keyword `float`; C also has `double` for double-precision floating point (in most modern languages, such as Python, the only floating point format supported is double-precision, but C is old enough that it defaulted to single-precision).

Answer (score 4):

In short **no**.

Every float is a real number, but not every real number is a float, for example there is no float equal to **pi**.

In fact floats are more related to rational numbers than real ones, but treating them as real numbers is just a useful mathematical abstraction.

Comment: I would just change the wording to "Every float represents a real number, but not every real number can be represented as float"